# C# difference between button events and custom class

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am trying to understand *events* and *delegates* and after 2 days of studying, it looks like I am still lost in basic understanding.

I wrote following code - `class UserControl` contains event definition. It works well, although the program is stucked in `Start()` method.

How for example `buttonClick` event is implemented? Does button object running in some kind of different thread - on order to be able to call a method whenever the button is clicked?

Thanks

```
    class UserControl
{
    public delegate void methodsControlDelegate();
    public event methodsControlDelegate methods;

    public void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (methods != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                this.methods();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        uc.methods += eventMethod; 
        uc.Start();
    }

    public static void eventMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EVENT METHOD");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I have modified the code for Windows Forms.

```
    class Writer
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public void writeMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Text);
    }
}
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        UserControl userControl = new UserControl();
        Writer writer = new Writer();
        userControl.WriteMessages += writer.writeMessage;
        writer.Text = "HELLO, HOW ARE YOU";
    }
}
class UserControl
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event EventHandler WriteMessages;
}
```

Comment: It's stuck in "Start()" because you have a while loop that never exits, which in turn will trigger eventMethod() every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to understand events and delegates and after 2 days of studying, it looks like I am still lost in basic understanding.

Take a step back.

```
class Customer
{
  private string name;
  public string Name { get { return this.name; } }
  public Customer(string name) 
  {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

A *property* is *logically a property of the class of things*.  Customers have a name, so `Customer`s have a property `Name`.

A *field* is *an implementation detail*. It is a *variable* that can store a *value*.

A *type* is an implementation detail of a field or property; it gives you a restriction on *what kind of data can be used as a value for this property*.

The *value* -- say "Barbara Smith" -- is the value associated with that property for a particular customer:  `new Customer("Barbara Smith")`.

If that is not all clear then you need to take a step back and understand that. You won't get events and delegates if you haven't got properties, fields and values down.

An event is like a property. It is a *logical feature of a class of things*.  Buttons can tell you that they are clicked, so `Click` is an event of `Button`.  The button will call you when it is clicked.

A delegate *type* is a restriction on *how* the button may call you when it is clicked.

A delegate *instance* is a delegate to a *particular* function that will be called when the button is clicked.

Is that now clear?

> How for example buttonClick event is implemented?

Understanding that requires you to understand how Windows works.

Every Windows program has a message queue which receives messages from the operating system.  When the user clicks a button, Windows puts a message in the queue for that process that says the button was clicked.  When the process handles that message, taking it out of the queue, it invokes the delegate associated with the click handler for the button.

> Does button object running in some kind of different thread - on order to be able to call a method whenever the button is clicked?

Nope.  If you hang the UI thread of your program so that it cannot remove the message from the queue then the button click handler is never invoked.

In fact it is *illegal* to call code in the button from any thread other than the UI thread.

Every time you've seen a Windows app hang, it's almost certainly because some badly-written code did not allow the message loop to take a message out of the queue in a timely manner.

You then go on to post some code with no explanation and no question.  I don't know why you posted that code. Try asking a more clear question.

That said, looking at the code you seem to be trying to do event handling from a console application. Don't do that.  **Console applications are not event-driven.**  Write a WinForms or WPF application if you want to make an event-driven application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. It really helped me for better picture. I have modified the code for windows forms.  What I would like to do (and not sure how to do) is to fire event whenever data are passed to `writer.Text`.

Comment: @Izmail360: Well, do you have a *change event* that occurs when `writer.Text` changes?  If so, then you can handle that change event, and have the event handler for the change event cause some other event to fire.

Answer (score 0):

`delegate` is an encapsulation on top of a method. It allows you to pass a method around, as a reference and execute it whenever you decide. The delegate defines a signature of a method and any method which is of the same signature can be used as that delegate.

`events` are one more level of encapsulation, this time on top of `delegate`s. It allows adding and removing (subscribing and unsubscribing) methods to it. And when the event fires, it will invoke each one of the added to it methods (delegates). This encapsulation is necessary, so that one 'client' of the event cannot override another client to the same event.